# SPOJ The Mirror of Galadriel (Runtime Error)

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to solve http://www.spoj.com/problems/AMR12D/ but I am getting the run-time error NZEC again and again.
Here is my code:

```
t=input()
while t:
    s=raw_input("")
    j=s[::-1]
    if j==s:
        print "YES"
else:
        print "NO"
t=t-1;
```

Can you tell me reason behind NZEC error?

Comment: did you submit it as formatted currently in your post? Also, that won't work, that just checks the reverse of the whole string. By the problem description, you need to check EVERY substring

Comment: but a palindrome string would have its image same and so every substring will also be same

Comment: Hm, you seem to be right. Can't think of a counter example :)

Comment: I erred as well. I didn't think this whole problem reduced to palindrome finding because I couldn't believe a problem on SPOJ could be that easy, lol

Comment: yeah i also can't believe same code in c giving wrong answer...but i think the logic is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what's suggested in examples on the site:

```
t=int(raw_input()) # first line of input is the number of cases
while t:
    s=raw_input() # read another string
    j=s[::-1]
    if j==s:
        print "YES"
else:
        print "NO"
t=t-1;
```

Comment: ah so they don't allow using `sys`? then you can try doing what they suggest. Updated my answer. I guess you have tried using another example, which was for Python 3.

Comment: do you submit it as Python 2.7? can you give the link to another RTE?

Comment: Most importantly, do you get this RTE from the test environment on SPOJ or from ideone?

Comment: For ideone, you had to provide input (like SPOJ did). Here are both variants actually working in ideone: http://ideone.com/iFnhPn and http://ideone.com/PuKZiR